# Why use HMAC.Initialize();

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography

I've seen code like this:

```
HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(key);
hmac.Initialize();
return hmac.ComputeHash(buffer);
```

But when I comment out the `Initialize` line - it works fine. So what does it do? **/** When do we need to use it? (The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmac.initialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) don't seem to explain it.)

Answer (score 5):

A newly created instance is already initialized. `ComputeHash` calls `Initialize` in the end. So you only need to call `Initialize` yourself if you use `TransformFinalBlock` directly.